# generic type : convert "number", "string" to real type

Tags: typescript-generics

i want to convert string of "string" and string of "number" to be real type.

````
```
  type IInputParams = {
    [key: string]: "number" | "string"
  }

  const dynamicParams: IInputParams = {
    name: "string",
    age: "number",
  }

  type IParams<K extends IInputParams> = {
    [Property in keyof K]: K[Property] extends "number"
      ? number
      : K[Property] extends "string"
      ? string
      : never
  }

  const exampleParams: IParams<typeof dynamicParams> = {
    name: "tom", // this line error name's type always be never. should be string
    age: 24, // this line error age's type always be never. should be number
  }

```
````

I  trying to learn generics and trying to make this code work, but it did not. I don't understand what the mistake is. Can anyone help guide me to pinpoint the problem? What is the mistake in this code, and how should I fix it? Thank you

Comment: Instead of doing const dynamicParams:... You should try const dynamicParams = {...} satisfies IInputParams

Comment: like (this)[https://tsplay.dev/mxzOxw]

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying the type of the dynamicParams variable manually.

For typescript 4.9+ use

```
const dynamicParams = {
    name: "string",
    age: "number",
} satisfies IInputParams
```

For typescript below 4.9, use `as const` which allows the compiler to infer all the fields of the object.

```
const dynamicParams = {
    name: "string",
    age: "number",
} as const
```

If you then want to enforce what can be put in the dynamicParams argument (to only allow "number" and "string"), you can use a separate assert function helper

```
export function assert<T extends never>() {}
type TypeContains<A,B> = Exclude<A,B>;

assert<TypeContains<typeof dynamicParams, IInputParams>>();
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkjB2YCuwAKBDATugtgZygF4oBvAKCkqgG0BrCEALij2EwEt4BzAXWYCJ4SHACMImflAA%20Ufqw7d%20ZAL5kyAYwD28VlAAmIeLnbqM2fEVIUoRnBAHzOXfgBpr6LvdlDR419b10YAgAeQAzACF2TGAACwc2JyVKAHoUqHQ9PUwIPDwBTREAKwh1YEk0qAA5TWAMgBt6zQB3CD0oERAoOOh0PPE69VjS2hUMgi0dYDUIAA8wTRioMKR4MvZtcbwBgB4AFSg54Pg9AngIADdxAD4ACgBKUlVQSCg98AgAYW1gdE48HYAQRcEWulgAorN1PUkHoIECQdcANxqPrbGL7D7feC-f47F4QTRhfSGYymLC4PAuWAIZBoCn4a53e4osgE2BmSk7ADSh1mx1ONMQKE5jMs5Eo1FQmE0kBiXU4UHoICJUG5fDVUplctAPD5AoIgmEYgk1koAH4bMbxGaoMxuVrZQMQHqjhATobHIpbZavVxbcxzldMCo1JNdHNcGB6hBRfkOQyAQTVQZbCY42DiBKbLgvPxgJocK4oJU-e5PMwAEwAFmplR8JoCQVCkWicWYABFmwA6eAtB4l9J7WIy5oEcQyzAdUroJDbfTN8JRGKxDLqdQQMDAAjaepdP14UNAA)